# My Font Manager Application not displaying font style correctly after Debian upgrade

Tags: python, linux, debian, gtk3, pangocairo

I've developed a Font Manager application using Python with Gtk and Glade for the UI, designed specifically for Debian-based distributions. Everything worked seamlessly until I upgraded Debian. Post the upgrade, the way fonts are displayed in the application has changed.

Before the upgrade:

- The font would be added to the list.
- The charmap of the font was displayed in the font's style.
- The example text was shown in the style of the selected font.

After the upgrade:

- The font still gets added to the list.
- The charmap appears, but not in the font's style.
- The example text is visible, but in a default style, **not in the font's style**.

Interestingly, if I restart the app or add another font, the display of the previously added font corrects itself. However, the font that's just been added still appears in the default style.

Here's a snippet of the code responsible for adding and selecting fonts: [a rustpad link](https://rustpad.io/#helpme)

Any insights or suggestions on why this might be happening and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

I noticed the behavior rectifies itself when I restart the application or add another font, which led me to suspect an issue with the Pango library. I tried removing the threading structure entirely and considered forcefully restarting the application through software means, though I'm aware this isn't an ideal solution.

I'm new to GTK application development and I'm puzzled as to how a Debian upgrade might have influenced this behavior. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has a solution, I'd greatly appreciate any insights.

Comment: Check for the obvious problem. Is the font in question installed in debian?

Comment: Yes, the fonts in question are indeed installed on Debian. When I check the system's font directory, I can confirm that the fonts have been successfully installed.
I'm adding fonts by copying them to the ~/.fonts/ directory and then refreshing the font cache with fc-cache -f. This method worked flawlessly prior to the upgrade. I'm wondering if there were any changes in the way GTK or Pango handles fonts in the newer version of Debian that might be causing this behavior.

Comment: I suppose you could try the same operation with the built-in font button and font selector and see if there is a similar caching issue.